# Magento 2: How to show amount at the bottom?

Tags: magento2.3

Currently, toolbar amount is showing at the top in the product listing page. And I want to show this at the bottom in the product listing page.

```
Items 1-8 of 32
```

Is there any way to do this without using CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bottom toolbar amount is hiding from style-m.css

if you want to quickly check the toolbar amount in the bottom then you can do this in same file (list.phtml) by style tag.

```
<style>
.products.wrapper ~ .toolbar .toolbar-amount {
    display:block;
}

.toolbar-amount {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

but include css in phtml file is not a good practice.

For this, you can create _extend.less file in your custom theme & put the below css.

```
//display toolbar at bottom
.products.wrapper ~ .toolbar .toolbar-amount {
    display:block;
}

//hide toolbar at top
.toolbar-amount {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much

Answer (score 2):

The tool-bar is already available at the bottom of products.

it is hide using CSS. You can remove `display:none` and it will start showing.

please see attached screen shot.

[image]

If you want to hide top `toolbar-amount` you can use:

```
.toolbar-amount {
    display: none;
}
.products.wrapper~.toolbar .toolbar-amount {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: wait let me check..

Comment: Yes, Now I want to remove the top tool amount. Can I do that with CSS?

Comment: See my updates in answer

Comment: thanks you so much

Comment: welcome @abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Override template Magento_Catalog:product/list.phtml in your theme (app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[your-theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml).

From here you can move toolbar block wherever you want.

```
<?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```